Apex Charts on Mudblazor .Net6
This is ApexChart Razor Page which is not showing any chart displays blank page. I want to implement ApexChart on MudBlazor .Net6
@page "/apexChart"
@using MudBlazor
@using MudBlazor.Charts

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
    var options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'sales',
            data: [30, 40, 35, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91, 125]
        }],
        xaxis: {
            categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999]
        }
    }

    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

    chart.render();
</script>
@code {
   
}


I was expecting to display apex chart in Mudblazor as it display in html code. The code below is html code for apex chart
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <div id="chart"></div>
<script>
var options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'line'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'sales',
    data: [30,40,35,50,49,60,70,91,125]
  }],
  xaxis: {
    categories: [1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997, 1998,1999]
  }
}

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

chart.render();
</script>
  </body>
</html>


https://github.com/apexcharts/Blazor-ApexCharts
